# Something blocking port 80

Tags: networking, server, apache2, netstat

So I'm trying to get Apache to run on AWS server again and I'm running into this error:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

I tried going ahead and running:

```
netstat -ltnp | grep :80
```

And the following results came back:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

What is using port 80? and how to do i kill it.
Or find where its coming from. Resetting the server / shutting it down produced no help.

So something is starting on port 80.. just not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display the names of the services by using `netstat` you need to run the command with root privileges. So you can use:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

Example output:

```
$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -e 'PID/Program\|:80'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address    State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::80             :::*               LISTEN      3309/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::8080           :::*               LISTEN      1273/java
```

Comment: thank you this helped alot!.

Comment: Hello, @c.naka, if this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) (by click on the grey tick ✓ left to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out. Regards.